# Waiting to Iterate until a function is done Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two functions one is getting the files in a directory using fs. The other is getting every line in a file using line-reader. I have them both independently working correctly but when i try and nest the line reader portion inside of the directory portion it doesn't wait until the entire function is complete before going to the next one.

Im expecting it go for
-open file
-run the internal function

- go to next file and repeat

here is the code ive tried put together.

```
 const lineReader = require('line-reader');
 var fs = require ('fs');
const { finished } = require('stream');
files = fs.readdirSync("./");
console.log(files)

for( file of files ){
  var doneFile ="NO"
  stockLine = "";
  stockDone = "not done"
  matDone = "not done"
  fileName = files[3].slice(0,-3);
  file = `${fileName}.NC`
  newFile = `STOCK ${fileName}.txt`
  console.log(newFile)
  
  lineReader.eachLine(file, function(line) {
      if(line.includes("(STOCK")||line.includes("(stock") ){
             console.log(line);
             stockLine = line;
            console.log("INSIDE FUNCTION", stockLine);
            console.log(stockDone)
            stockDone = "DONE"
            console.log(stockDone)
         };
      if(line.includes("(MAT")){
         matLine = line
          console.log(matLine);
          matDone = "DONE"
      };
     if((matDone == "DONE") & (stockDone == "DONE")){
         textOut = stockLine + matLine
         console.log("I FOUND BOTH");
          fs.writeFile(`${newFile}`, `${stockLine}  ${matLine} `, function (err) {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log('Saved!');
            });
        doneFile="YES"
         matDone = "stop"
         
      }
      });
    };
```

Comment: You should consider whether or not you actually need these to run in order. It's a valid thing to want to do, but be aware that processing the files in parallel might end up being faster. It's up to you to decide which way is best.

Comment: I just took a quick glance at the notes for the [line-reader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-reader) module and it appears that `eachLine` is asynchronous by design.  The example says to [_promisify_](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-reader#promises) the `eachLine` function if you need to do something after all the lines have been processed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `lineReader.eachLine` runs asynchronously (see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-reader#promises)). You could try [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to convert this into a function that returns a `Promise`, then `await` that promise. For example,

```js
const lineReader = require('line-reader');
const util = require('util');

const eachLinePromisified = util.promisify(lineReader.eachLine);

(async () => {
    for (const file of files) {
        /* ... */
        await eachLinePromisified(file, (line) => { /* ... */ });
    }
})();
```

Comment: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules. THis is what i got when I added in the code you showed.

Comment: Right, [top-level await](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await) is not supported everywhere. You need to put this `for` loop in an `async` context. I updated the answer accordingly.